# How to perform a cumulative sum but maintain zero values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cumsum

I need to do a cumulative sum in MATLAB, for a matrix of zeros and ones for each row, but I need to stop it when there are no more ones. Example, if I start with:

```
A = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0];
```

I want the result:

```
B = [0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0];
```

If I use `cumsum`, it will continue adding the values and give another result:

```
B = [0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 5;
     0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 7;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 2 2];
```

Please, if someone has any suggestion as I can't find something similar (I have several quite large matrix).

Comment: This question should be migrated to Stack Overflow since it's code based.

Answer (score 4):

There are two potential solutions depending on how you want to handle a case where you have more than one string of ones per row (if that is a possibility). If you want the cumulative sum to reset every time a new string of ones is encountered, use the more complex solution. If you don't want the cumulative sum to reset for each new string of ones, or you only ever have one string per row, use the simpler solution:

- **Simple solution (one string or no cumsum resetting):** You can perform the cumulative sum, then use `A` (specifically its [negation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/not.html)) as a [logical index](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) to set entries back to zero:

  ```
  B = cumsum(A, 2);
  B(~A) = 0;

  B =

       0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5     0     0     0
       0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     0     0     0
       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     0     0     0     0
  ```
- **Complex solution (reset cumsum for each string):** Let's say you can have more than one string of ones per row, such as (notice the last row):

  ```
  A =

       0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
       0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
       0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
  ```

  In this case, we can take the values of the cumulative sum at the end of each string of ones, place those in a new matrix, apply [`cummax`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cummax.html), then subtract from our cumulative sum:

  ```
  B = cumsum(A, 2);
  index = find([zeros(size(A, 1), 1) diff(A, 1, 2)] == -1);
  C = zeros(size(B));
  C(index) = B(index);
  B = B-cummax(C, 2);

  B =

       0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5     0     0     0
       0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     0     0     0
       0     0     0     1     2     0     0     1     2     0     0     0     0
                                                 ^-- sum resets
  ```

  Applying the simpler solution in this case would instead yield:

  ```
  B =

       0     0     0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5     0     0     0
       0     0     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     0     0     0
       0     0     0     1     2     0     0     3     4     0     0     0     0
                                                 ^-- no reset
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Find the cumulative sum of A and get positions of zeros in A and replace zero at these positions in the cumsum.

```
A = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0];

B = cumsum(A,2) ;
B(A==0) = 0 ;
```